# Chrome extension: how to recognize and display PDF in new tab instead of downloading with specific headers

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, browser-extension

I have developed an extension that cancels download of PDF file and open the file on new tab, but it only works when it hits 3 conditions:

1. When you know absolute path to PDF file by `chrome.downloads.onCreated` API
2. When `content-disposition: attachment` is detected on `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` listener
3. When `content-type: application/pdf` is detected on `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` listener

But it doesn't work on this website (demo):

You can go to [the page](https://minzdrav.sakha.gov.ru/Kadrovoe-obespechenie/otdel-kadrov-i-upravlenija-personalom) (do not be terrified if you see that's in russian) and try to download the first PDF or instead just go to download a file on this URL: https://minzdrav.sakha.gov.ru/files/front/download/id/1381567

You'll see that response headers are:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: must-revalidate
content-description: File Transfer
content-disposition: attachment; filename="img-701190411.pdf"
content-length: 322722
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Thu, 09 Jul 2020 03:37:43 GMT
expires: 0
pragma: public
server: nginx
set-cookie: isloggedin=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; domain=sakha.gov.ru
status: 200
```

And this specific request meets only one of my conditions:

- ✔ `content-disposition: attachment` means "download the file". Its value has to be changed to `inline` to prevent downloading of file.
- ❌ `content-type: application/octet-stream` probably means "download as stream with no clue what the file type is". But I do not know how to recognize whether it is a PDF file or not
- ❌ both `downloadItem.url` and `downloadItem.finalUrl` in `chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(downloadItem => {})` listener do not contain an absolute path for PDF file. How to get an absolute path?

### The question

How to detect if this is a PDf file and open the file on new tab instead of downloading, on the website mentioned above?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you need an absolute path and why chrome.downloads API is needed here. At least IIUC any webRequest listener will give it in `url` property so there should be no problem. As for (3) the only solution is to check `.pdf` inside `content-disposition` header.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for an optimization trick! Is there's may be a situation when it's a PDF file but without `.pdf` or without filename inside `content-disposition` header?

Comment: I don't think so. That would be a broken site because even the browser wouldn't be able to guess the type. Either `Content-Type` or an extension inside the attachment name or inside the URL should be present.